# how to set dynamic select items in react-multi-select-component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import MultiSelect from "react-multi-select-component";
const Example = () => {
  const options = [
    { label: "Grapes", value: "grapes" },
    { label: "Mango", value: "mango" },
    { label: "Strawberry", value: "strawberry", disabled: true },
    { label: "Watermelon", value: "watermelon" },
    { label: "Pear", value: "pear" },
  ];
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
return (
  <div>
   <h1>Select Fruits</h1>
   <pre>{JSON.stringify(selected)}</pre>
   <MultiSelect
    options={options}
    value={selected}
    onChange={setSelected}
    labelledBy="Select"
   />
  </div>
 );
};

export default Example;
```

This code is working fine. But i'm not getting how to checked items dynamically. how should i passed checked value for 2 and 3 options if i want. Thank in advance

Comment: Are you having an issue selecting multiple items or are you trying to set the starting value?

Comment: i'm able to select multiple options. after setting  value={[...]} i'm not able to select any other option or not able to de-select which are already checked

Comment: is the "Custom Value Renderer" can be used for this purpose 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-select-component

Comment: I just copied your original code you posted and it works fine. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @scott, this code is working fine. But what i tried is, I want to select first 2 values by default. so for that i used value={[{ label: 'Grapes', value: 'grapes' },
    { label: 'Mango', value: 'mango' },]}.    In this case i'm able to select first 2 values. But if i want to unselect first one and select 3 or 4 it's not allowing.

Comment: @Rao I think I understand what you want now --- see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the list to initialize with pre-selected items, you need to pass the selected prop correctly. Currently you pass an empty array. Try this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import MultiSelect from "react-multi-select-component";
const App = () => {
    const options = [
          { label: "Grapes", value: "grapes" },
          { label: "Mango", value: "mango" },
          { label: "Strawberry", value: "strawberry", disabled: true},
          { label: "Watermelon", value: "watermelon" },
          { label: "Pear", value: "pear" },
        ];
  // preset some selected values for first render
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(options.slice(0,2)); 
  
  return (
      <div>
           <h1>Select Fruits</h1>
           <pre>{JSON.stringify(selected)}</pre>
           <MultiSelect
                 options={options}
                 value={selected}
                 onChange={setSelected}
                 labelledBy="Select"
                />
          </div>
     );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi Scott, i'm able to checked values using this solution. but not able to check or uncheck options. any suggestion

Comment: Thank you @scott, this working exactly how i need.